# Behat/Mink find element by xpath

Tags: html, behat, mink

I am trying to access an element using XPath in Behat and Mink context an element which has no but my function can't seem to find it

Here's the element structure:

```
 <a data-iskeynav="true" data-test-id="compose-button" href="/d/compose/4661075315" class="e_dRA l_T cn_dBP cg_FJ k_w r_P A_6EqO u_e69 p_R S_n C_52qC I_Z1UEcsX D_F H_6VdP gl_C ab_C en_0 M_1Eu7sD ir3_Z1FS2Mn it3_dRA" role="button" 
aria-label="Compose" tabindex="20">Compose</a>
```

And here's my php code

```
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element = $page->find('xpath', '//a[@data-test-id = "' . $id . '"]');
```

I even used this XPath, copied by the browser but with no success

```
//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a
```

Comment: We'll need more context - at least as much as the XPath suggests (e.g. all the divs leading to that a).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a condition to that `a`, that has a certain attribute with value or contains some value in the attribute

Examples:

css: `#app a[data-test-id=compose-button]`
css: `#app a[href*=compose]`

xpath: `//*[@id='app']//a[@data-test-id='compose-button']`
xpath: `//*[@id='app']//a[contains(@href, 'compose')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `contains` keyword:

It should be:

```
//a[contains(@data-test-id, '"'. $id . '"')]
```